# Access events in one app from another app

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app. I need it to be able to monitor user's actions in another app (from another developer), for example detect if person clicked somewhere in this app. Is it possible?

Comment: Thankfully no, this is impossible (at least using public APIs meant for the App Store).

Comment: if you register your apps as appgroup you can share the data between apps http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios8-app-groups

Answer (score 0):

The following document on [inter-app communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) by Apple discusses how you can share information, but you will need cooperation from the other developer(s) for this to work. You cannot (thankfully!) listen in on another app based on how iOS isolates apps while running.